# Call component function that inside a page from another page

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I'm trying to understand how I can trigger OnSwipe from inside another JS file called CardFooter.js containing a button with OnClick triggering OnSwipe from the previous JS file called CardItem.js. They both are called inside Card.js.

I'm learning Nextjs with Reactjs components. Any insight would greatly be appreciated

**CardFooter.js**

```
import { CardItem }  from '../components/CardItem'

const CardFooter = () => { 

   return (
   
       <Button onClick={() => CardItem.onSwipe('left')}></Button>;
       <Button onClick={() => CardItem.onSwipe('right')}></Button>;

   )
}

export default CardFooter
```

**CardItem.js**

```
import { useState, useContext, createContext } from 'react'
import { Context } from '../context/Context'
import TinderCard from 'react-tinder-card'
import { test } from '../components/CardFooter';

export const CardItem = ({ card }) => {

  const { handleRightSwipe, handleLeftSwipe, currentAccount } = useContext(Context)

  const onSwipe = dir => {
    if (dir === 'right') {
      handleRightSwipe(card, currentAccount)
    }
    if (dir === 'left') {
      handleLeftSwipe(card, currentAccount)
    }
  } 

  return (
    <TinderCard
      preventSwipe={['up', 'down']}
      onSwipe={onSwipe}
    >
    <div style={{ backgroundImage: `url('${card.imageUrl}')` }}>
    <div>
      {card.name}
    </div>
  </div> 
</TinderCard> 
)
}

export default CardItem
```

**Card.js**

```
import { useContext } from 'react'
import { Context } from '../context/Context'
import CardFooter from './CardFooter'
import CardItem from './CardItem'

const Card = () => {

const { cardsData } = useContext(Context)

  return (
    <div className={style.wrapper}>
      <div className={style.cardMain}>
        <div className={style.swipesContainer}>
          {cardsData.map((card, index) => (
            <CardItem card={card} key={index} />  
          ))}
        </div>
      </div>
      <CardFooter  />
    </div>
  )
}

export default Card
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In React, you **can't** pass props up from child components into parent components. This means that you wouldn't be able to pass the `handleSwipe` function up to `<CardFooter>`.

But it doesn't look like you'd need to do that anyways, since you have the `handleRightSwipe` and `handleLeftSwipe` functions within your `Context`, and all the `handleSwipe` function is really doing is calling those functions.

So, with this in mind, there are two solutions:

1. In your footer, import the context and use it, then when the user clicks on the right button, call `handleRightSwipe`, and `handleLeftSwipe` for the left button. (this is the naive solution)
2. Define `handleSwipe` within the parent `<Card>` component, then pass it as a prop to both of the components. This way, you only need to define the function once. (ideal solution)

Comment: @askmeaquestion1234 For sure! I really do recommend going with the second solution. Otherwise you'll be repeating code you don't need to.

Comment: Agree with you.

Comment: Best of luck on your Tinder clone :P Super interested in the project

Comment: haha thanks! I'm learning for now. Always fun to try and rebuild existing projects to learn